# Jupyter kernel problem caused by pyenv+pipx

Tags: python, jupyter, pyenv, pipx

I installed two versions of python in *pyenv*, python3.7.5 and 3.8.6.
I usually use python3.8.6, so it is globally activated (`pyenv global 3.8.6`).

I also installed *pipx* by `pip install pipx` within python3.8.6 to install *jupyter lab* globally (`pipx install jupyterlab`), which is located in `~/.local/pipx/venvs/jupyterlab`.

It seems that there is one jupyter kernel pre-installed.

```
$ jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
  python3           ~/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

When I execute `jupyter lab`, this kernel is automatically selected.
However, in *jupyter lab*, I cannot import *numpy*, which is installed in python3.8.6.

```
[1]: import numpy as np

[1]: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
     ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
     <ipython-input-1-0aa0b027fcb6> in <module>
     ----> 1 import numpy as np

     ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

This may be due to a PATH setting.

```
[2]: import sys
     sys.path

[2]: ['~/',
     '~/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/python38.zip',
     '~/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/python3.8',
     '~/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
     '',
     '~/.local/pipx/venvs/jupyterlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages',
     '~/.local/pipx/shared/lib/python3.8/site-packages',
     '~/.local/pipx/venvs/jupyterlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
     '~/.ipython']
```

`~/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages` should be in `sys.path`. Why is not this path included?

Comment: Install the kernel somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use pipx. Type "pipx inject jupyterlab numpy scipy matplotlib etc etc etc."
This will install those modules into the jupyterlab virtual environment.